# Pick random element subset from map

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, c++11, random

I have a map of elements:

```
   std::map<char,int> values;

   values['a']=10;
   values['b']=30;
   values['c']=50;
   values['d']=70;
   values['e']=90;
   values['f']=100;
   values['g']=120;
```

So I need to pick N elements from `values` as a map of pairs preferably (output format as well as input format).

I tried other different solutions from stackoverflow but they mostly applicable for vector not for any type of C++ 11 container or looks too complicated for me.

I need some more effective way than just `random_shuffle` which actually mutates C++ container.

Also it would be nice if this function would be applicable for any type of C++ container.

Comment: What about `std::sample`?

Comment: std::sample is C++ 17 feature

Comment: But you can copy its [implementation from some standard library](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L5933).

Comment: @Evg `std::sample` doesn't work with map as well. I've checked it doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 3):

You could copy the keys of the `std::map<char, int>` into an `std::vector<char>`. Then, shuffle this vector with [`std::random_shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)<sup>X</sup>. Finally, return `num` elements of the map: the ones whose keys are the `num` last keys in the vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> pick_random(const std::map<char, int>& m, size_t num)
{
   std::vector<char> keys;
   keys.reserve(m.size());

   // copy the map's keys    
   std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(keys),
      [](const std::pair<const char, int>& p) {
         return p.first;
      }
   );

   // shuffle the keys
   std::random_shuffle(keys.begin(), keys.end());

   // number of elements to pick
   num = std::min(num, m.size());

   std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> res;
   res.reserve(num);

   // pick num elements
   std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(res), num,
      [&keys, &m]() {
         auto it = m.find(keys.back());
         keys.pop_back();
         return *it;
      }
   );

   return res;
}
```

The idea is to randomly shuffle the elements in the vector containing the keys (i.e., `keys`). Therefore, you shuffle the keys, which map to elements in the map. You use these randomly shuffled keys to obtain elements from the map in a random way.

---

<sup>X</sup>or [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) insted since `std::random_shuffle` has been deprecated in C++14 and removed in C++17.

Comment: Fyi, `std::random_shuffle` is deprecated in C++14, removed outright in C++17. Use [`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) with a properly provided urng argument.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Looks like it's the only option

Answer (score 0):

`std::sample` is C++17, but you can implement it yourself pretty easily in C++11. For example, for forward iterators (and `std::map` iterator does satisfy this requirement) typical implementation relies on the selection sampling algorithm. Its description can be found in Vol.2. of Knuth's [TAOCP](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/taocp.html), p.142.

Simplest implementation:

```
template<class Forw_it, class Out_it, class URBG>
void sample(Forw_it first, Forw_it last, Out_it out, std::ptrdiff_t n, URBG&& g) {
    auto sz = std::distance(first, last);
    n = std::min(n, sz);

    while (n != 0) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<std::ptrdiff_t> d(0, --sz);
        if (d(g) < n) {
            *out++ = *first;
            --n;
        }
        ++first;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
std::map<char, int> values;
// ... assign values ...

std::vector<std::pair<char, int>> vec;
sample(values.begin(), values.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), 4, std::mt19937{});

for (auto p : vec)
    std::cout << p.first << ' ' << p.second << '\n';
```

Sample output:

```
b 30
e 90
f 100
g 120
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fi-QTC)